# How to send input from template to a view in django

Tags: django, templates, view

I need some help. I'm a new in django. I want to get the input and print it in the second textarea. I tried but really don't know how can I do it. 
I know that I'm wrong but don't know how to fix it and do it. help!

This is my index.html

```
 <form method='POST' action=''> 
   <tr><td align="left"> question: </td>
   <td colspan="5">
   <input name="quest" type="text" value= "{{quest}}" size="40"  
 maxlength="200" value=""><font color="DimGray" size="2"> ask yr question:</font> </td>
   </tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td height="23"></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td>
   <br><button type="submit">Search</button> {% csrf_token %}   
 </form>

 <td align="left"> le passage </td>

 <FORM>
   <TEXTAREA name="nom" rows=4 cols=40>{{res}}</TEXTAREA>
 </FORM>
<td align="left"> les textes </td>

 <FORM>
   <TEXTAREA name="nom" rows=4 cols=40>{{aff}}</TEXTAREA>
 </FORM>
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def affich(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    question = request.POST['quest']
    var = question.POST.get('value')
    aff = var.get_value()
return render(request,"index.html",{'aff': aff})
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^index/','journal.views.affich',name='index'),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create the form not in your template, but you have to create it in your view and pass it to the template.

Read [Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/)

Example form in forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.CharField(label='Message', max_length=80)
```

Example view in views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import ExampleForm

def example_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExampleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            field1 = form.cleaned_data['field1']
            # Do what you gotta do.
            return HttpResponse("")
    else:
        form = ExampleForm()
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

Example template file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Your Example Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="ExampleForm" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```